# Xamarin Forms Tap Gesture Two Taps specifically cause Object reference not set to an instance of object

Tags: .net, xaml, xamarin.forms

Odd issue... But if I specifically try to use 2 taps, as a double tap (quick taps), to interact with my page, I get an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." Error.

However if I use 1 NumberOfTapsRequired or 3 NumberOfTapsRequired, everything works fine.  No error.  Code runs as expected.

Why would specifically 2 taps throw an error?  Slowly tapping with a manual counter doesn't generate the error.  So it's specifically some double tap issue.

I've also tried using a counter under the Tapped event and then calling code after counting 2 taps.  Same problem.  It's... weird.

```
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Black" Padding="20,10,20,10">
            <Label x:Name="basemessage"  Text="Base Message"
                VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" 
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Transparent" TextColor="White" FontSize="30">
                <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer x:Name="tappedmessage" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" Tapped="screentapped_Tapped"></TapGestureRecognizer>
                </Label.GestureRecognizers>
            </Label>
            <Label x:Name="itemslist"  Text="Items List"
                VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" 
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Transparent" TextColor="White" FontSize="30">
                <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer x:Name="tappedlist" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" Tapped="screentapped_Tapped"></TapGestureRecognizer>
                </Label.GestureRecognizers>
            </Label>
            <Button x:Name="closedialog" Text="Continue..." TextTransform="None"
                VerticalOptions="End" 
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Transparent" TextColor="White" FontSize="25"
                Clicked="closedialog_Clicked"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: please post the stack trace for the exception

Comment: double tap is a bad design anyways , use long press

Comment: I'm not getting a stack trace.  I've got all CRL Runtime exceptions enabled.  Tried enabling all Javascript exceptions (testing in Android) and nothing.  No exception details and no stack trace.

Comment: I test your code with NumberOfTapsRequired=2 in both iOS and Android and it all works well on my side. I can't reproduce the issue.