# Xamarin Forms Tap Gesture Two Taps specifically cause Object reference not set to an instance of object in system or framework code

Tags: android, xamarin

I am experimenting with Xamarin.  I am using the Collection View with Swipe Items.  In the datatemplate I am using a grid that has a gesture recognizer.  I am using the community toolkit's Tabview and this collectionview is in 1 of three tabs.  There is also a flyout page.

I found setting NumberOfTapsRequired="2" in a collection view causes an object reference error.

When I remove it, it all runs fine.

Anyone have insights?

[Earlier question from another user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64337499/xamarin-forms-tap-gesture-two-taps-specifically-cause-object-reference-not-set-t)

```
<CollectionView x:Name="testList"
          BackgroundColor = "AntiqueWhite" EmptyView="No items yet!"
          ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsAvailable}"
          Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="5"
          Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="6"
          >
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <SwipeView>
                <SwipeView.LeftItems>
                    <SwipeItem Text="Edit"
                               BackgroundColor="Green"
                               Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:testListViewModel}}, Path=OnEditItem}"
                               CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                               />
                </SwipeView.LeftItems>
                <Grid RowSpacing="1" ColumnSpacing="1" >
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="140" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                    <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding CurrentDayNumber}" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                    <Label Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding DateUpdate}" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                    <!-- Separator -->
                    <BoxView HeightRequest="1"
                       BackgroundColor="Black"
                       Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                       Grid.Row="2"
                       VerticalOptions="End"/>
                    <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer 
                        Tapped="AdventureListItem_Tapped"
                            NumberOfTapsRequired="2"
                        Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:testListViewModel}}, Path=ItemTappedCommand}"       
                        CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                    </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                </Grid>
            </SwipeView>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

[image: Screen upon hitting error]

Messages after hitting "Continue" 3 times.

```
**System.NullReferenceException:** 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

The thread 0x10 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #16
Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #10
The thread 0xa has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #12
The thread 0xc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0xd has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #13
Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #15
The thread 0xf has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #8
**System.NullReferenceException:** 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI NewString called with pending exception android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.InnerGestureListener.HasAnyGestures () [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\InnerGestureListener.cs:59 
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.InnerGestureListener.Android.Views.GestureDetector.IOnGestureListener.OnDown (Android.Views.MotionEvent e) [0x00007] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\InnerGestureListener.cs:99 
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.Platform_DefaultRenderer.n_onTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent) (Platform_Default02-04 11:44:09.798 F/e.testapp(10245): java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at (wrapper dynamic-method) Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.122(intptr,intptr,intptr)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.InnerGestureListener.n_onDown(android.view.MotionEvent) (InnerGestureListener.java:-2)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.InnerGestureListener.onDown(android.view.MotionEvent) (InnerGestureListener.java:39)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean android.view.GestureDetector.onTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent) (GestureDetector.java:630)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.Platform_DefaultRenderer.n_onTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent) (Platform_DefaultRenderer.java:-2)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.Platform_DefaultRenderer.onTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent) (Platform_DefaultRenderer.java:48)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent) (View.java:13415)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent, boolean, android.view.View, int) (ViewGroup.java:3054)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent) (ViewGroup.java:2741)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.Platform_DefaultRenderer.n_dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent) (Platform_DefaultRenderer.java:-2)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.Platform_DefaultRenderer.dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent) (Platform_DefaultRenderer.java:56)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent, boolean, android.view.View, int) (ViewGroup.java:3060)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent) (ViewGroup.java:2698)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.SwipeViewRenderer.n_dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent) (SwipeViewRenderer.java:-2)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.SwipeViewRenderer.dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent) (SwipeViewRenderer.java:72)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent, boolean, android.view.View, int) (ViewGroup.java:3060)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent) (ViewGroup.java:2698)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent, boolean, android.view.View, int) (ViewGroup.java:3060)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent) (ViewGroup.java:2698)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent, boolean, android.view.View, int) (ViewGroup.java:3060)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent) (ViewGroup.java:2698)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.Platform_DefaultRenderer.n_dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent) (Platform_DefaultRenderer.java:-2)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.Platform_DefaultRenderer.dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent) (Platform_DefaultRenderer.java:56)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent, boolean, android.view.View, int) (ViewGroup.java:3060)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent) (ViewGroup.java:2698)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.Platform_DefaultRenderer.n_dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent) (Platform_DefaultRenderer.java:-2)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.Platform_DefaultRenderer.dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent) (Platform_DefaultRenderer.java:56)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent, boolean, android.view.View, int) (ViewGroup.java:3060)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent) (ViewGroup.java:2698)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent, boolean, android.view.View, int) (ViewGroup.java:3060)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent) (ViewGroup.java:2698)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent, boolean, android.view.View, int) (ViewGroup.java:3060)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent) (ViewGroup.java:2698)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.Platform_DefaultRenderer.n_dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent) (Platform_DefaultRenderer.java:-2)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.Platform_DefaultRenderer.dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent) (Platform_DefaultRenderer.java:56)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent, boolean, android.view.View, int) (ViewGroup.java:3060)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent) (ViewGroup.java:2698)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.Platform_DefaultRenderer.n_dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent) (Platform_DefaultRenderer.java:-2)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.Platform_DefaultRenderer.dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent) (Platform_DefaultRenderer.java:56)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent, boolean, android.view.View, int) (ViewGroup.java:3060)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent) (ViewGroup.java:2698)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.Platfor02-04 11:44:09.799 F/e.testapp(10245): java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.Platform_DefaultRenderer.n_dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent) (Platform_DefaultRenderer.java:-2)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.Platform_DefaultRenderer.dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent) (Platform_DefaultRenderer.java:56)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent, boolean, android.view.View, int) (ViewGroup.java:3060)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent) (ViewGroup.java:2698)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.VisualElementRenderer_1.n_dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent) (VisualElementRenderer_1.java:-2)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent, boolean, and02-04 11:44:09.799 F/e.testapp(10245): java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent, boolean, android.view.View, int) (ViewGroup.java:3060)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent) (ViewGroup.java:2698)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent, boolean, android.view.View, int) (ViewGroup.java:3060)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent) (ViewGroup.java:2698)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean android.vi02-04 11:44:09.799 F/e.testapp(10245): java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent) (ViewGroup.java:2698)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent, boolean, android.view.View, int) (ViewGroup.java:3060)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent) (ViewGroup.java:2698)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent, boolean, android.view.View, int) (ViewGroup.java:3060)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent, boolean, android.view.View, int)02-04 11:44:09.799 F/e.testapp(10245): java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent) (ViewGroup.java:2698)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent, boolean, android.view.View, int) (ViewGroup.java:3060)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent) (ViewGroup.java:2698)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent, boolean, android.view.View, int) (ViewGroup.java:3060)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent) (ViewGroup.java:2698)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent, boolean, android.view.View, int) (ViewGroup.java:3060)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean a02-04 11:44:09.799 F/e.testapp(10245): java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.PlatformRenderer.n_dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent) (PlatformRenderer.java:-2)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.PlatformRenderer.dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent) (PlatformRenderer.java:55)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent, boolean, android.view.View, int) (ViewGroup.java:3060)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent) (ViewGroup.java:2698)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent) (ViewGroup.java:2698)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent, boolean, android.view.View, int) (ViewGroup.java:3060)
[e.du02-04 11:44:09.799 F] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent) (ViewGroup.java:2698)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent, boolean, android.view.View, int) (ViewGroup.java:3060)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent) (ViewGroup.java:2698)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent) (ViewGroup.java:2698)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent02-04 11:44:09.799 F/e.testapp(10245): java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent, boolean, android.view.View, int) (ViewGroup.java:3060)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent) (ViewGroup.java:2698)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent) (DecorView.java:465)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent) (Activity.java:3993)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at void android.view02-04 11:44:09.799 F/e.testapp(10245): java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent) (WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent) (WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent) (DecorView.java:423)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at boolean android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(android.view.MotionEvent) (View.java:13674)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at void android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(android.view.ViewRootImpl$QueuedInputEvenva_vm_ext.cc:570]   at int android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(android.view.ViewRootImpl$QueuedInputEvent) (ViewRootImpl.java:5482)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at int android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(android.view.ViewRootImpl$QueuedInputEvent) (ViewRootImpl.java:5285)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at void android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(android.view.ViewRootImpl$QueuedInputEvent) (ViewRootImpl.java:4788)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at void android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(android.view.ViewRootImpl$QueuedInputEvent) (ViewRootImpl.java:4841)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at void android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(android.view.ViewRootImpl$QueuedInputEvent) (ViewRootImpl.java:4807)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at android.os.Message android.os.MessageQueue.niewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(android.view.ViewRootImpl$QueuedInputEvent) (ViewRootImpl.java:4947)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at void android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(android.view.ViewRootImpl$QueuedInputEvent, int) (ViewRootImpl.java:4815)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at void android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(android.view.ViewRootImpl$QueuedInputEvent, int) (ViewRootImpl.java:5004)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at void android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(android.view.ViewRootImpl$QueuedInputEvent) (ViewRootImpl.java:4788)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at void android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(android.view.ViewRootImpl$QueuedInputEvent) (ViewRootImpl.java:4841)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]     from boolean cuedInputEvent) (ViewRootImpl.java:4807)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at void android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(android.view.ViewRootImpl$QueuedInputEvent, int) (ViewRootImpl.java:4815)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at void android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(android.view.ViewRootImpl$QueuedInputEvent) (ViewRootImpl.java:4788)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at void android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(android.view.ViewRootImpl$QueuedInputEvent) (ViewRootImpl.java:7505)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at void android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents() (ViewRootImpl.java:7474)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at void android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(android.view.InputEvent, android.view.InputEventReceiver, int, boolean) (ViewRootImpl.java:7435)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at void android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(android.view.InputEvent) (ViewRootImpl.java:7630)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at void android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(int, android.view.InputEvent) (InputEventReceiver.java:188)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at void android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(long, int) (MessageQueue.java:-2)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at android.os.Message android.os.MessageQueue.next() (MessageQueue.java:336)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:174)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:7356)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at void com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (RuntimeInit.java:492)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]   at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:930)
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570] 
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]     in call to NewString
[e.testapp] java_vm_ext.cc:570]     from boolean crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.InnerGestureListener.n_onDown(android.view.MotionEvent)
[libc] Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x40 in tid 10245 (e.testappe), pid 10245 (e.testappe)
```

Comment: if you think you have a reproducible test case, submit a bug for XF

Comment: Can you please try setting the selectionMode of the collectionView to none

Comment: @AmjadS. I added it, put back the taps required to 2.  Same error.  I changed the number of taps to 3 and nothing happens.  Changed it to 1 and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to the code below. It works well for me.

The same xaml as yours.

Mode:

```
public class test
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string CurrentDayNumber { get; set; }
    public string DateUpdate { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class testListViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<test> ItemsAvailable { get; set; }
    public Command OnEditItem { get; set; }
    public Command ItemTappedCommand { get; set; }

    public testListViewModel()
    {
        OnEditItem = new Command(() =>
          {
              Console.WriteLine("OnEditItem");
          });

        ItemTappedCommand = new Command(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ItemTappedCommand");
        });
        ItemsAvailable = new ObservableCollection<test>()
        {
            new test(){ Name="A", CurrentDayNumber="1", DateUpdate= "2022/12/01"},
            new test(){ Name="B", CurrentDayNumber="2", DateUpdate= "2022/12/01"},
            new test(){ Name="C", CurrentDayNumber="3", DateUpdate= "2022/12/01"},
        };
    }
}
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class Page9 : ContentPage
{
    public Page9()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BindingContext = new testListViewModel();
    }

    private void AdventureListItem_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("AdventureListItem_Tapped");
    }
}
```